# C# Reflection. Set TableAdapter ConnectionString

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, tableadapter

I've been trying to create a new base class for a Windows Forms form.  I want to have this base class go through all the tableadapters it has on it and update their connection strings without anyone adding any code to the form.  They just put the tableadapters on the form and don't worry about the connection string settings as it's all handled in the base class.

The problem is my reflection code can find the property fine, but it can't set it. How can I fix it?

Below is the code:

```
public class cFormWS : Form
{
    public string ConnectionStringToUse { get; set; }

    public cFormWS()
    {
        Load += cFormWS_Load;
    }

    void cFormWS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitiliseTableAdapters();
    }

    private void InitiliseTableAdapters()
    {
        var ListOfComponents = EnumerateComponents();

        foreach (var ItemComp in ListOfComponents)
        {
            if (ItemComp.ToString().ToLower().EndsWith("tableadapter"))
            {
                var ItemCompProps = ItemComp.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties();

                var TASQLConnection =
                    ItemCompProps.FirstOrDefault(
                        w => w.PropertyType == typeof(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection));

                if (TASQLConnection != null)
                {
                    var property = typeof(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection).GetProperty("ConnectionString");

                    // How do I set the value?

                    string value = "some new connection string";

                    var ConvertedProperty = Convert.ChangeType(value, property.PropertyType);

                    // I tried seting a value. It is not working:
                    // "object does not match target type"
                    property.SetValue(TASQLConnection, ConvertedProperty, null);

                    //// I tried using a method. It is not working:
                    //// "object does not match target type"
                    //var m = property.SetMethod;
                    //ParameterInfo[] parameters = m.GetParameters();
                    //m.Invoke(m, parameters); // m.Invoke(this, parameters); // m.Invoke(ItemComp, parameters);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<Component> EnumerateComponents()
    {
        return from field in GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
               where typeof(Component).IsAssignableFrom(field.FieldType)
               let component = (Component)field.GetValue(this)
               where component != null
               select component;
    }
```

Comment: You dont need reflection here (or your code does not make any sense of its intended usage).

Comment: To my knowledge there is no other way to do what I want in an automated fashion.

Comment: That would only be true if TableAdapters do not share a common base class. Does it? MSDN is rather vague on this.

Comment: And even in that case, you can still avoid reflection by applying a known interface to the generated class and cast `ItemComp` to that.

Comment: TableAdapter is inherited from Component.  Applying an interface to the generated class would mean that when it is regenerated it would lose the interface no?

Comment: No, there should be a file generated for usercode the first time it is created.

Comment: I looked at I can actually override the base class of each tableadapter so could use a different class and do things differently.  BUT this is a long as it is wide.  It doesn't solve the problem. If I'm to update all my tableadapters I may as well write the code when I use them.  I'm after an automatted non invasive solution which my reflectioncode should/would fix if I could get the setvalue to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `SetValue`, you need to pass in the object that you wish to set the property on.

- In your first example code, you passed in `ItemComp`: This is incorrect, since the `ConnectionString` is a property of the `SqlConnection` which is a property of `ItemComp`
- In your edited question (and my original answer) you pass in the `TASqlConnection`. However, this is not the object, but a `PropertyInfo`based of the object
- The correct way is to get the value from the `ItemComp` object and pass that in:

`property.SetValue(TASQLConnection.GetValue(ItemComp), ConvertedProperty, null);`

ORIGINAL (INCORRECT) ANSWER:

You're trying to set a `ConnectionString` property of `ItemComp`. The ConnectionString is not a property of the `TableAdapter`, but of the `SqlConnection` (which is a property of the `TableAdapter`).

The correct way of setting the property would be this:

```
property.SetValue(TASQLConnection, ConvertedProperty, null);
```

Comment: Nope.  Same error message.  I'd already tried lots of different combinations.

Comment: Yep, the issue is that you're passing in the `PropertyInfo`-object, not the actual object. See my edited answer for an explanation and the fix

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It's still not working though.  I now have a different error.  

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: Have a look at the innerexception. If you're using your sample code, the connection string is not in a correct format and the actual assignment will fail

Comment: Yes you are right.  I didn't think it would need to be a valid connection string as it isn't connected at that point but it looks like the set checks it.