# How to identify strongly typed tableAdapter in form

Tags: c#, vb.net

I need to be able to switch the connection string dynamically when the user selects it (via radio button during login). 
I do have the connection string, that's not an issue.  It can not go into the app.config because of above.

That said, I think if I can find the strongly typed table adapter within the form I can programmatically switch the connection string.  But I can't find it.

I looked at this post which didn't quite get me to anything useful.  [C# Reflection. Set TableAdapter ConnectionString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048117/c-sharp-reflection-set-tableadapter-connectionstring)

Any ideas where this would be?  It's not the controls collection, it's not in Me.GetType().GetMethods() and not in Me.GetType().GetProperties.

Added some code per request, not sure how helpful this is.  This is set on login.

```
   If frmPreferences.InProd Then
        GConnectString = "DATA SOURCE=xxx;PASSWORD=" & Password & ";USER ID=" & userName & ";"
    Else
        GConnectString = "DATA SOURCE=xxx;PASSWORD=" & Password & ";USER ID=" & userName & ";"

    End If
```

Here is some other code which allows me to set the config string during runtime, but it's for each tableadapter.

```
Me.INSTITUTIONSTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = GConnectString
Me.INVOICESTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = GConnectString
```

Any suggestions welcome.  The intent is to not refactor the 100+ datasets and 500 forms.  If I need to make a small change to each dataset that's fine, but it wouldn't be feasible to trash all of the datasets and do everything programmatically as someone suggested (it would likely take several years).

Comment: Make use of a connection class...

Comment: Can you share the code which switches between the connections?

Comment: Something very similar to this was asked recently, but frustratingly I can't find it.  However, it's better practice to create your dataset and tableadapter in code, ideally in a Data Access Layer, rather than rely on the designer adding it to the form. That way you will easily be able to change the connection on the tableadapter too.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya done.

Comment: @Codexer  Can you give any guidance on this?  This may be the route to take.  Google fu is failing me.  I know there were same changes in VS 2010 which allow a strongly typed dataset to set the connection string programmatically , but seemingly the code is lost every time you generate the dataset.

Comment: I've located the [SO question I was thinking of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103423/finding-all-datasets-on-a-windows-devx-form) - hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is resolved, the solution is to modify in memory the app.config file, and reload it.  When the app first launches, depending on if the user is in prod or dev, it does this:

```
If frmPreferences.InProd Then
    GConnectString = "DATA SOURCE=xxx;PASSWORD=" & Password & ";USER ID=" & userName & ";"
Else
    GConnectString = "DATA SOURCE=xxx;PASSWORD=" & Password & ";USER ID=" & userName & ";"
End If

Dim config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
Dim connectionStringsSection = CType(config.GetSection("connectionStrings"), ConnectionStringsSection)
connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings("RADS.My.MySettings.RPCOracleConn").ConnectionString = GConnectString
config.Save()
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings")
```

The bottom code is from a SO post:  [Change connection string & reload app.config at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502411/change-connection-string-reload-app-config-at-run-time)

I'm still slightly concerned about two users launching the same EXE, but I will figure it out.